# How to add a new QR Code function to Moodle Mobile (written in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, moodle, moodle-mobile

I am tasked with adding a QR code generating feature to Moodle Mobile. But I have no idea where to start as I have little knowledge of Javascript.

The below image (see link) shows a quick sketch of how I want the mobile app to look like (the image is captured from PC Firefox)

In this case I want to:

1. Add a "QR Code" button to the menu bar.
2. When clicked, will take the user to a QR Code "Page" in which the user can enter a string then see the corresponding QR code generated immediately.

I have already done the QR code segment which is by davidshimjs

I tried inspecting elements using Firefox but I cannot find where do I "add a button" to the menu bar, not to mention where do I add a new "page" to the app. So I would like to know **how do I integrate the QR code functionality into the Moodle app** (add the button + connect to the QR code page)? Do I need to create a new plugin and how do I do that?

Your help is much appreciated.

[Sketchup of how my Moodle app should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8eDp.png)

[X-posted from Moodle.org forums](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=347071)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu bar should be located in /www/core/components/sidemenu/templates/menu.html, there you could simply add a new entry, like

```html
<li>
   <a menu-close class="item item-icon-left" ng-href="{{siteinfo.siteurl}}" mm-link auto-login="yes" title="{{ 'mm.sidemenu.website' | translate}}">
      <i class="icon ion-earth"></i>{{ 'mm.sidemenu.website' | translate}}
   </a>
</li>
```

Nevertheless, getting the QR stuff inside your app would require some advanced knowledge of the app and Angular JS. I wrote already some Angular desktop applications, but still I did not find any time to work on Moodle mobile, since it would take some time to get into it.

So easiest workaround for you would maybe:

- Implementing only hardcoded "external" link in the app
- Show the QR page in regular browser

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I was wondering what you said about "getting the QR stuff... advanced knowledge of the app & Angular JS", I can get the source code (Javascript) running fine on my browser perfectly. Does that mean I cannot directly "copy and paste" the JS for the QR code directly into my Moodle Mobile source code? My project requires me to generate a QR code from a variable string (and probably requires some AES encryption)

For your reference the QR code library I was using is from [here](http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/)

Comment: >Does that mean I cannot directly "copy and paste" the JS for the QR code directly into my Moodle Mobile source code?  - Yes, indeed. You would have to put it at least into some angular controller and so on, which requires some more advanced knowledge. Basically in "moodle mobile terms" you would have to create a addon, like for example "www/addons/calendar/". As mentioned above, quick&dirty way would be an external link, nice way having at least a custom angular modul which will show your QR page inside app